# JDBC connection to MSSQL server in windows authentication mode

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc

In my following programme I am trying to connect MSSQL Server using jdbc in windows authentication. But getting following error

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

class  Cms_truncate
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

         //String name="cmscim";
         //String filename = "D:\\programs\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\timescape\\canteen_scheduller\\CMS_CSV\\cms_cim\\"+ name+"-"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) +"-" +(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-"+cal.get(Calendar.DATE)+".csv";
         Connection conn = null;
         String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databasename=CMS_TIMES_MAIN;integratedSecurity=true";
         String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
         String userName = ""; 
         String password = "";
         Statement stmt;
         try
         {

         Class.forName(driver);//.newInstance();
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
         String query = "select * from cim where sapId=10025331";
         stmt = conn.createStatement();
         int flag = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
         System.out.println("flag = "+flag); 
         conn.close();
        System.out.println("");
         } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }
}
```

I am using SQL Server in windows authentication mode.
Do I need to do set up other things to connect MSSQL using jdbc in windows authentication.

ERROR:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Cms_truncate.main(Cms_truncate.java:28)
```

Comment: and have you done what is suggested in the error message?

Comment: Well have you set up SQL server to allow TCP/IP connections on port 1433? It sounds like you haven't.

Comment: I am not getting that error .please help what to do

Comment: @Jon : How to do that? Do i need any dll's to set up it

Comment: @yatinbc: Go into your SQL Server administration tool, and enable TCP-IP connections. If that's not enough information for you, search the web for how to do this - I'm sure it's covered in a lot of places.

Comment: Does it work well with you when using SQL Server authentication user and password?

Comment: @MohammedAlaghbari Probably not, as the error has nothing to do with windows authentication: the driver isn't even able to connect to the database server.

Answer (score 22):

Using windows authentication:

```
String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://PC01\inst01;databaseName=DB01;integratedSecurity=true";
```

Using SQL authentication:

```
String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://PC01\inst01;databaseName=DB01";
```

Comment: How to do this on AIX system ? (sqljdbc_auth.dll won't work in AIX)

Comment: How it works on Linux

Answer (score 17):

Try following these steps:

1. Add the `integratedSecurity=true` to JDBC URL like this:

   ```
   Url: jdbc:sqlserver://<<Server>>:<<Port>>;databasename=<<DatabaseName>>;integratedsecurity=true
   ```
2. Make sure to add the sqljdbc driver 4 or above version (sqljdbc.jar) in your project build path:

   ```
   java.sql.DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
   System.out.println("Driver version:" + metaData.getDriverVersion());
   ```
3. Add the VM argument for your project:

   - Find the *sqljdbc_auth.dll* file from DB installed server `(C:\Program Files\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86)`, or download from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774).
   - Place the dll file in your project folder and specify the VM argument like this:
     VM Argument: `-Djava.library.path="<<DLL File path till folder>>"`

     NOTE: Check your java version 32/64 bit then add 32/64 bit version dll file accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add sqljdbc_auth.dll in your C:/windows/System32 folder. You can download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774 .

Comment: this is also a correct answer, plus setting integratedSecurity=true in the url.

Comment: In my opinion it's not correct to put this dll in `Windows\System32` directory. It'll be better to put in other new directory and add this to `PATH` variable.

Comment: Pretty much that. Rewriting the `-Djava.library.path` has unintended side effects. For example losing other system libraries that java loads.

Answer (score 7):

From your exception trace, it looks like there is multiple possibility for this problem

1). You have to check that your port **"1433"** is blocked by firewall or not. If you find that it is blocked then you should have to write "Inbound Rule". It if found in control panel -> windows firewall -> Advance Setting (Option found at Left hand side) -> **Inbound Rule**.

2). In SQL Server configuration Manager, your **`TCP/IP`** protocol will find in disable mode. So, you should have to enable it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable the SQL Server TCP/IP Protocol in Sql Server Configuration Manager app. You can see the protocol in SQL Server Network Configuration.

Comment: Answer is correct, we need to Enable TCP/IP by going to above path. But after doing this also need to restart the SQL Server service to take our changes. You can find this service in same --- Server Configuration Manager app.

Answer (score 3):

i was getting error as "This driver is not configured for integrated authentication" while authenticating windows users by following jdbc string

> `jdbc:sqlserver://host:1433;integratedSecurity=true;domain=myDomain`

So the updated connection string to make it work is as below.

> `jdbc:sqlserver://host:1433;authenticationScheme=NTLM;integratedSecurity=true;domain=myDomain`

**note**: username entered was without domain.

Answer (score 2):

For the current MS SQL JDBC driver (6.4.0) tested under Windows 7 from within DataGrip:

1. as per [documentation on authenticationScheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-2017) use fully qualified domain name as host e.g. `server.your.domain` not just `server`; the documentation also mentions the possibility to specify `serverSpn=MSSQLSvc/fqdn:port@REALM`, but I can not provide you with details on how to use this. When specifying a fqdn as host the spn is auto-generated.
2. set `authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos`
3. set `integratedSecurity=true`
4. use your unqualified user-name (and password) to log in

As this is using JavaKerberos I would appreciate feedback on whether or not this works from outside Windows. I believe that no .dll is needed, but as I used DataGrip to create the connection I am uncertain; I would also appreciate Feedback on this!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do windows authentication, use the latest MS-JDBC driver and follow the instructions here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should copy your .dll => here "mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.0.x64.dll" in that folder => sqljdbc_9.4\enu\auth\x64  to your Java JDK/bin.

**Shortly:**  =>  sqljdbc_9.4\enu\auth\x64\mssql-jdbc_auth-9.4.0.x64.dll
to Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin

If it doesnt work, you can open your SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration , all protocol's name should be Enabled. After that you should click on (TCP/IP) / IP Addresses, you will see that IPALL-> TCP PORT should be  1433.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot, I finally found a solution, here we go -

Download the file `jtds-1.3.1.jar` and `ntlmauth.dll` and save it in Program File -> Java -> JDK -> jre -> bin.

Then use the following code -

```
String pPSSDBDriverName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
Class.forName(pPSSDBDriverName);
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<ur_server:port>;UseNTLMv2=true;Domain=AD;Trusted_Connection=yes");
stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql = " DELETE FROM <data> where <condition>;
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: Don't put it in JDK/JRE `bin` directory! It'll fail if you update JDK/JRE. Better put `ntlmauth.dll` file in a custom, new directory anywhere you want (not jdk location) and add this directory to the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Nop, you have a connection error, please check your IP server adress or your firewall.

**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."**.

1. ping yourhost (maybe the ping service was blocked, but try anyway).
2. telnet yourhost 1433 (maybe blocked).
3. Contact the sysadmin with the results.