# How to access SQL Server database from iccube builder

Tags: iccube

I am trying to connect to SQL server from iccube Web UI, but when I set up the Data Source connection like this

```
Name: TestDataBase
DriverType: SQL Server
ServerName: localhost
DB Name: TestDataBase

User: MyWindowsUserName
Password: **********
```

(my windows username and password).

, I got the following error:

```
JDBC connection for url 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestDataBase;' and user 'MyWindowsUsername' cannot be created due to error 'Login failed for user 'MyWindowsUsername'.
```

What am I missing, and can I somehow use integratedSecurity so I can login with my windows credentials as I do from SQL Server Management studio.

Comment: I have just managed to log in with SQL Server Authentication, just don't know  if I can log in with Windows credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to setup the connection string as mentionned by Hermes (or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497998/jdbc-connection-to-mssql-server-in-windows-authentication-mode)) using the "Server Name" and "DB Name" to define the actual JDBC class name and connection string (check the help icons closed to each fields):

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I made a progress, populated fields like on your picture but now I am getting an error: Failed to load tables from data source 'SQL Server' due to the following error: 'Database 'true' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.'

Comment: After a while it turned out that it is order of connection parameters: with this connection string I succeded: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;databaseName=TestDatabase         - so databaseName must be in the last place, and it must not have ; at the end because it will be considered as a part of database name. So, thank you very much on your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try 
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestDataBase;integratedSecurity=true;

Comment: I wanted to do exactly that, but in this screen where I am putting this connection parameters, there is no option to enter or check integrated security. I have a problem with uploading picture of that screen, but I do not see that option.