# JAVA - How to Connect spring boot application with SQL server 2016 (which has windows authentication)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, windows-authentication, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL server 2016.

and my application.property file is

spring.datasource.data-username=DDS-NA/njain

spring.datasource.data-password=

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=photo-app

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

[image]

I am getting "Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" error. could someone guide me?

Comment: Add the integratedSecurity=true to JDBC URL: `jdbc:sqlserver://<<Server>>:<<Port>>;databasename=<<DatabaseName>>;integratedsecurity=true`

References in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48980393/8207836)

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

Comment: This link can help you https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-microsoft-sql-server/

Comment: Tried it too,not working.

Answer (score 1):

Please download the drivers from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Add the jar to your project
Right Click on `project - > Build Path -> Configure Build Path - > Libraries -> Add External JARs`

And add the `integratedSecurity=true` to JDBC URL: `jdbc:sqlserver://<<Server>>:<<Port>>;databasename=<<DatabaseName>>;integratedsecurity=true`

You don't have to specify username and password for Windows Authentication