# Issues connecting to localhost with windows authentication for mssql

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to connect to my localhost database.

This is a screenshot from MSSQL Mangement Studio with the basic credentials:

[image: ms sql credentials]

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-HF5N51H\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=ETA
spring.datasource.username=DESKTOP-HF5N51H\\Zafir Stojanovski
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

When I run my application, I get the following error:

```
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-HF5N51H\Zafir Stojanovski'. ClientConnectionId:948051cf-bfe3-4cba-ad57-8a05d01afeab
```

I don't understand. Should there be a different application.properties configuration for windows authentication?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20184475) topic will be helpful...

Comment: Could you connect to SqlServer via Sql Server Authentication rather than Windows Authentication ?