# Java connection to a SQL Server Login failed for user

Tags: java, sql-server

I want to connect to sql server 2017

I try without error to connect to sql server using sql server management studio

[image]

and I execute some query like :

```
 SELECT fullname
 FROM [AssetInst.Integ].[dbo].[Employee]
```

my problem now is to connect using java hibernate.

I use **sqljdbc4.jar** and **jdk 1.6**

first I try  with this java class to test connexion:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {

       try
       {

            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());   

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.12\\MSSQLSERVER2017:1433;databaseName=AssetInst.Integ","Test_user","P@ssw0rd123@");


            String query =" select * FROM [AssetInst.Integ].[dbo].[Employee]";
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                System.out.print("fullname: " + resultSet.getString("fullname"));                
            }
       }catch(Exception ex)
       {
            ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

but I have this error :

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'Test_user'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2529)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1905)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1893)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1045)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.dq.hibernate.generator.Snippet.main(Snippet.java:27)
```

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497998/jdbc-connection-to-mssql-server-in-windows-authentication-mode

Comment: **Remove `:1433`** from the connection URL. When you specify both instance name and port number, the port number takes precedence, and port 1433 is used for the unnamed instance.

Comment: thank you a lot, the problem is solved when I remove the port number

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
connectionMsSQl = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:sqlserver:/192.168.0.12;instanceName=AssetInst.Integ, "Test_user", "P@ssw0rd123@");
```

check  name and password. try this one hope its works for you