# Can't connect to SQL Server using netbeans

Tags: sql-server, netbeans

I created a new database in SQL Server(first time using it) after choosing **Windows Authentication** as an Authentication type
[image: As you can see in the pic]

Then I tried to add the SQL Server to netbeans 
[image: pic2[![][2]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vihAJ.png)

But when I try connecting to the database I always get a connection error
[image: pic4]

Comment: Sorry but your first image (and images are discouraged for many reasons) does not indicate you "created a database". SSMS and the SQL Server database engine are different downloads. Did you install SQL Server or just SSMS? If the latter, then you need to do the former.

Comment: Actually I installed both(as far as i know, when i finished installing SQL Server it prompted that i might want to install SSMS so i did)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that NetBeans won't grab your current user credentials because that isn't how Java powered applications typically work, esp. when it doesn't have an authentication type selector. Have you tried actually typing them in "User Name" and "Password"?

Comment: If it can actually be done, you'll probably need to set details in the JDBC URL. Here's the first [Google hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497998/jdbc-connection-to-mssql-server-in-windows-authentication-mode) I found to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

### Check the MSSQL port

First, you need to check that MSSQL indeed listens on the default port 1433. To check it run the script [or use other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297475/how-to-find-sql-server-running-port):

```
USE master
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on' 
GO
```

In my case, it listens on 1444, so you might need to change the port in JDBC connection string:

[image]

### Choose version of sqljdbc_auth.dll

Second, to use integrated security you need to put [sqljdbc_auth.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22691421/5681468) in NetBeans bin path (in my case for 8.1 it's  C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 8.1\bin).

The  sqljdbc_auth.dll ships with [Microsoft JDBC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54671) and you can find it in sqljdbc_4.2\enu\auth\x64 (or x86) directory.

You need to choose the right version of sqljdbc_4.2.  If NetBeans uses x86 version of java then choose x86 version of sqljdbc_auth.dll. You can check it with NetBeans in *Help -> About*. In my case it uses x86 version:

[image]

If you have x64 version then it would look something like this:

[image]

### Change jdbc connection string

After that add **integratedSecurity=true** to the JDBC URL for example:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://SRV-01\SQL2008R2:1444;integratedSecurity=true
```

To check other JDBC related issues you can find log in *View -> IDE Log* menu. Hope this helps.