# How to connect SQL server in tibco (jdbc connection)?

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, tibco

I want to connect my SQL server with tibco jdbc connection in window authentication mode.

Comment: You should use a search engine for this kind of thing first. There are literally thousands and thousands of examples all over the internet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows authentication mode in TIBCO BusinessWorks using the two following approaches :

## In Windows environment

You can use the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver (that is bundled in BusinessWorks 6.X). In order to manage Windows authentication you need to have the 'sqljdbc_auth.dll' file somewhere in the BusinessWorks PATH.

Then in the JDBC URL definition make sure to include the following element : integratedSecurity=true

For example : jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydb;integratedSecurity=true

For details you can refer the following stack overflow article :
[JDBC connection to MSSQL server in windows authentication mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497998/jdbc-connection-to-mssql-server-in-windows-authentication-mode)

## In an Unix environment you can use the TIBCO JDBC driver for SQLServer ('tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver')

Then in the JDBC URL definition make sure to include the following element :
authenticationMethod=ntlmjava;Domain=

Example :
jdbc:tibcosoftwareinc:sqlserver://host:1433;databaseName=master;authenticationMethod=ntlmjava;Domain=EMEA